# unable to generate csv file or attendance system

Tags: python, csv, opencv

i'm trying to make an attendance system so i check every code i find online and try to run it to see which one works and not so i can make it as my guide. Below is the code i am trying to run:

```
import datetime
import os
import time

import cv2
import pandas as pd


#-------------------------
def recognize_attendence():
    recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()  # cv2.createLBPHFaceRecognizer()
    recognizer.read("TrainingImageLabel/Trainner.yml")
    harcascadePath = "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml"
    faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(harcascadePath)
    df = pd.read_csv("StudentDetails/StudentDetails.csv")
    cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
    col_names = ['Id', 'Name', 'Date', 'Time']
    attendance = pd.DataFrame(columns=col_names)

    while True:
        ret, im = cam.read()
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.2, 5)
        for(x, y, w, h) in faces:
            cv2.rectangle(im, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (225, 0, 0), 2)
            Id, conf = recognizer.predict(gray[y:y+h, x:x+w])

            if(conf < 100):
                ts = time.time()
                date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
                timeStamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(
                    ts).strftime('%H:%M:%S')
                aa = df.loc[df['Id'] == Id]['Name'].values
                tt = str(Id)+"-"+aa
                attendance.loc[len(attendance)] = [Id, aa, date, timeStamp]

            else:
                Id = 'Unknown'
                tt = str(Id)
            if(conf > 1):
                noOfFile = len(os.listdir("unknown"))+1
                cv2.imwrite("unknown/Image"+str(noOfFile) +
                            ".jpg", im[y:y+h, x:x+w])
            cv2.putText(im, str(tt), (x, y+h), font, 1, (255, 255, 255), 2)
        attendance = attendance.drop_duplicates(subset=['Id'], keep='first')
        cv2.imshow('im', im)
        if (cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q')):
            break
    ts = time.time()
    date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    timeStamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    Hour, Minute, Second = timeStamp.split(":")
    fileName = "Attendance/Attendance_"+date+"_"+Hour+"-"+Minute+"-"+Second+".csv"
    attendance.to_csv(fileName, index=True)
    cam.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

    print("Attendance Successfull")
```

basically it will serve as the recognizer of the said system. The camera will load to gather face data and then it will check the trained data who is in the gathered data and then after it will generate the result on a csv file which include the name, and id of the recognized data. The camera works and it also displays the name and the id of the who is in front of the camera but   is unable to generate a csv file. I'm pretty much new to this and i've been practicing so sorry if you find my question  basic.

Comment: do you have the Attendance folder created in the same folder from where you are running the code ?

Comment: Yes it is in the same folder. I named it Attendance

Comment: any error you get ? or it simply goes on and displays attendance successfull ?

Comment: No i'm not having any error it just wont generate the csv file which is the point of the proj.

Comment: And also the camera wont stop unless you close the terminal even if you press esc.

Comment: were you able to print the dataframe ? right before the line it is saved to file ?

Comment: I dont think i have encountered that

Comment: okay. try printing the dataframe and see, if you have got the values, or to check does it throw any exception.

Comment: aa = df.loc[df['Id'] == Id]['Name'].values is this it?

Comment: you can simply put attendance.tail() to see the values in the attendance df.

Comment: Can you save an empty file as csv ?   is  it  Attendance/Attendance_   or Attendance\\Attendance_  ?

Comment: I am working on raspberry pi so Attendance/Attendance works

Comment: i cant seem to follow you with the attendance.tail(). i'm still a noob

Comment: print( attendance.tail())   or print(attendance) to  check it's content before saving

Comment: Where will i put it?

Comment: before   this line :  attendance.to_csv(fileName, index=True)  (you're saving the file here)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202851/discussion-between-ziri-and-jess-elardo).

Comment: print( attendance.tail()) or print(attendance) doesnt work

Comment: What was the output ? empty ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use a debugger and check if your file path and data are correct.

[image]

Comment: I'll try it next week. I just got home. Thank you btw.